# Python3 のインストールの仕方

Tags: python3

独学プログラマーという本を購入しました。　
そこにはPython3をインストールする必要があると書かれていました。　
ですが説明動画が英語でわかりません。
日本語で教えてくださる方、いませんか。

Comment: PythonをインストールしようとしているコンピュータとOSの種類と版数などを追記してみてください。というかそれらとインストールをキーワードに検索すれば直ぐに色々と見つかります。また今はインストールせずともWeb上で使える環境などもあります。

Comment: 動画で公開されている内容をこの一問一答形式のサイトで答えるには範囲が広すぎる印象です。

Comment: 公式のドキュメントをみてセットアップするのがいいと思います。わざわざ本を買わなくても教えてくれるなんて、良い世の中になりました。https://docs.python.org/ja/3/using/index.html

Comment: 「ですが説明動画が英語でわかりません。」とのことですが、字幕機能を使っても分からないでしょうか？（それとも字幕機能がない動画ですか？）

Answer (score 2):

書籍に訳注を付けてありますので、そちらをご参照ください。

> ［訳注1］ 動画は英語ですが、インストール手順が分かりやすく紹介されています。日本語での手順は以下を参照してください。
> http://www.python.jp/install/install.html
> http://pycamp.pycon.jp/textbook/1_install.html